# How to move fles from windows 10 to ubuntu directory

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

where can I find the GUI of the ubuntu home directory which is installed from Windows 10 Microsoft store.

how can I move the files present in the C directory of windows 10 to one of the directory in the ubuntu

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?  When you start the file manager by clicking the Icon that resembles a folder in the launch bar you will automatically be in your home directory.  By default the your home directory is in `/home/[youruserid]`.  There you will find a number of sorted default folders such as `Documents`, `Videos`, `Download`, `Pictures`, etc.

Comment: @L.D.James OP seems to be talking about Windows Subsystem For Linux hence that isn't relevant

Comment: I see, the OP changed the content of his question.

Comment: Eh, there is no GUI. You installed a command line version of Bash. Nothing else. And even then: if there is any explorer type GUI it would be Windows software and provided by microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

The /home directory of "Bash of Ubuntu on Windows 10" is, from the W10 point of view, something like :

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows*\LocalState\rootfs\home
```

with

```
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\<myself>\AppData\Local
```